# Initilialize Navigation Property when creating new Entity with Breeze

Tags: breeze, navigation-properties

I have simple Model defined as

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, currently If I try to create a new Project Entity with breeze, it initializes the navigation property "Status" with `null`. How can I initialize it with default value? Note that, I don't want any binding with drop down field for this field at least for create operation.

```
function createNewProject() {
     return manager.createEntity('Project');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom constructor for the `Project` entity type and set a default `StatusId` value in there. The `Status` navigation property will be set to the relevant status entity (assuming the entity is in the breeze cache). For example:

```js
function Project() {
    this.StatusId = desiredDefaultStatusEntityId;
}

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('...');
manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Project', Project);
```

Take a look at [**Extending entities**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) for some more information on extending entities.

Comment: I already tried this out, but it throws an error: "Cannot assign a navigation property in an entity ctor". I don't think we can set the navigation properties like this. Any suggestion

Comment: Ahh, I see. How about trying to set the StatusID, and hopefully breeze to look up the Status object by ID: `this.StatusID = desiredDefaultStatusID`

Comment: yes, that works. But do you think, it's a good approach? If I set it with dropdown, it works fine. Why I have to set using StatusId if I want to initialize it with default option?

Comment: Yes, I think this is a fine approach. Ultimately the value of the `Status` navigation property is derived from the `StatusId` ID property, so setting the ID property is quite fine. I'll update the answer to describe this.

Comment: OK. But I did not set the property in the constructor. That not works, I set the statusId after creating a new Entity like vm.StatusId=1;

Comment: This works for me  function createNewProject() {

            return manager.createEntity('Project', {statusId: 1 });
}

Comment: It sounds like a default value for StatusId is being applied and overwriting the value set in the constructor. Does it work if you try doing the initialization in an initializer function (which will get called after default values have been applied) rather than a constructor function? 

To do this, change the `registerEntityTypeCtor` call to:

`manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Project', null, Project);`

Comment: I did, getting an error "Cannot set property 'StatusId' of undefined"

Comment: Ahh yes - the Project() function will need a bit of tweaking to be used as an initializer: the entity to initialize is passed as a parameter, not accessible via `this`. Change it to:

`function Project(p) { p.StatusId = desiredDefaultStatusId; }`

Comment: OK. That error messages goes away, but when I tries to save an entity getting the following error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Project_dbo.Status_StatusId". The conflict occurred in database "DataStore", table "dbo.Status", column 'Id'.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Tried to set property without using camelcase. p.statusId works great. Thanks a lot. Can you please update your answer, I will mark as answer

Comment: Can you do some tracing (on the database, or look at the HTTP network traffic going back to the server when saving) to see what `StatusId` value is being saved to the database? Also, are you using Knockout so that the `StatusId` value ends up as a Knockout observable? I'm not sure it will explain the FK error upon save, but if you are using Knockout then setting `StatusId` in the initializer should be done as follows: `p.StatusId(desiredDefaultStatusId)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56065/discussion-between-chrisg-and-user3398887).

Comment: could you please help me to resolve another issue related to breeze: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461068/how-to-load-navigation-property-from-cache