# Breeze - How to Load Navigation property from cache

Tags: breeze

I am getting a single entity by using a method `fetchEntityByKey`, after that I am loading navigation property for the entity by `entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty`. But `loadNavigationProperty` always make a call to the server, what I am wondering if I can first check it from cache, if it is exist then get it from there otherwise go the server. How is it possible? Here is my current code

```
  return datacontext.getProjectById(projectId)
        .then(function (data) {

             vm.project = data;
             vm.project.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty('messages');
 });
```

Here is a function that I encapsulated inside `datacontext` service.

```
 function getProjectById(projectId) {

            return manager.fetchEntityByKey('Project', projectId)
                .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {

                return data.entity;
            }
        }
```

Also, how is it possible to load `navigation property` with some limit. I don't want to have all records for navigation property at once for performance reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EntityQuery.fromEntityNavigation method to construct a query based on an **entity** and a **navigationProperty** .  From there you can execute the resulting query locally, via the EntityManager.executeQueryLocally method.  So in your example once you have a 'project' entity you can do the following.

```
var messagesNavProp = project.entityType.getProperty("messages");
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityNavigation(project, messagesNavProp);
var messages = myEntityManager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

You can also make use of the the EntityQuery.using method to toggle a query between remote and local execution, like this:

```
query = query.using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
```

vs

```
query = query.using(FetchStrategy.FromServer);
```

Comment: and these latter queries are asynchronously structured for the caller whether the query is in fact synchronous against cache or async against the server.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look here: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html
as you can see fetchEntityByKey ( typeName  keyValues  checkLocalCacheFirst ) also have a third optional param that you can use to tell breeze to first check the manager cache for that entity

hope this helps

Comment: I am talking about to get navigation property from cache, I already finished dealing with 'fetchEntityByKey' and it's cache. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: you can still use that to get navigation property also you can use executeQueryLocaly in order to query the manager cache